# How to determine the current thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

While calling methods (I mean calling these methods anywhere: in a random method of a random class, a subclass, an inner class...) like wait(), notify(), I wanna make sure that the current thread owns the object's monitor, otherwise, IllegalMonitorStateException will be thrown. Is there a way to check what the current thread is? and if possible, change the current thread to some other thread?

Comment: Sounds like a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Usually you should know whether your thread has a lock at any given point.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the current thread is, it matters whether the current thread has the objects monitor. eg, `Object obj` to have it's monitor you need to be within a synchronized block, `synchronized(obj){ //here}` If you don't know if you're in a synchronized block, then just assume you're not.

Comment: Are you asking  *how to find the current thread* or *how to find which thread owns a monitor*?

Comment: I want to know the current thread, so I can know what monitor it owns.:)

Comment: Did you see `Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: @CloudWalker, If somebody reading your code sees `o.wait()`, and if it's not immediately obvious that the call is inside a `synchronized(o)` block for the same object `o`, then your code is too complicated. If I was your teammate, reviewing your code, I would reject it.